# How do I keep track of my Bricklink orders?

Tags: bricklink, inventory

I just noticed "This order will be purged from the BrickLink website on …" on the bottom of one of my Bricklink orders.

How do I keep track of the inventory I bought on Bricklink after the orders are deleted? Can I somehow create an inventory from them? I just want to know which bricks I bought in an accessible manner.

Answer (score 7):

*Good answers here. As all of them suggest to download ordered items and manage your orders in an offline manner.*

Another way is to, keep track of your collection (sets and loose/extra bricks) online in Rebrickable. Here you you have an option to import orders directly from Bricklink.

Click the  Import/Delete Parts button on the Part List page that you want to import into.

[image: Import Parts from File or Website]

Choose a file or external site to import from.

From a [Rebrikable help guide](https://rebrickable.com/help/lists-parts/).

Answer (score 6):

If you go to your order overview, you can click on Download[image]

On the next page select the checkbox 'Include detail items'[image]

This should give you and overview of all orders including exact parts bought in each transaction.

Answer (score 5):

To add to @user18321’s answer, here are two other ways:

1. Within BrickLink: go to each order and click on “Add to Wanted List”. Now add the pieces to either a new wanted list (perhaps under the order number?) or dump all your orders into one big Wanted list (e.g. “Purchases”).
2. Using BrickStore: download this free software, give it your BL credentials, and it will download your orders for you (Using “Import”>”Bricklink Orders”). It has a great UI that allows you to manage your collection, and amongst others allows you to pull up current cost values for the items you own (ctrl-A ctrl-G).